# Launching application using Appium

Tags: selenium, appium

I have used the following code to launch an app. I didn't get any error log in Appium but application has not been launched.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();  
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android");
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");  
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");  
  capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
  capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.whatsapp");  
  capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.whatsapp.Main");  
  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);  
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
  driver.quit();
```

Please advice

Comment: Try commenting that `driver.quit();` line

Comment: You are trying to set browser capability and also activity capability plus a driver.quit. Are you working on a native app or web application? Also use the AndroidDriver instead of RemoteWebDriver.

Answer (score -1):

at the start you need to add this it is path of apk file

```
File app=new File("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Appium/Appium/node_modules/appium/apk/app-release-2.0.apk");
```